# How to return multiple data via StreamController?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mvvm

I'm trying to fetch markers in the google map dynamically and change the marker colour, on DB update. I'm successfully manage to fetch the markers on google map but I couldn't able to listen to the marker updates in `firestore` correctly.

This is my `profiles` db structure. `profiles` collection contains list of profile basic details.

[image: profiles db structure]

And each `profile`(document) contains an `attendance` sub-collection, which consists of, `date` as document and attendance data.

[image: attendance db structure]

I fetched markers in the google map, by looping through `profiles` collection. Now, I'm struggling to check each `profile`(document) -> `attendance` -> date -> `is_coming`: true or false, if is it `false` I've to update the colour of the specific marker.

This is how I'm trying to listen to each attendance record.

```
  final StreamController<Attendance> _attendanceController =
      StreamController<Attendance>.broadcast();

  Stream checkAttendance({String member, String batch}) {
    _profileCollectionReference //profiles collection
        .document(member)
        .collection('attendance')
        .document(toDate) //date
        .snapshots()
        .forEach((snapshot) {
      var data = Attendance.fromData(
          data: snapshot.data, profileId: member, batchId: batch); //returns as Attendance type

      _attendanceController.add(data);
    });

    return _attendanceController.stream;
  }
```

The problem is, it just returns the last record only or overwrites previous records. This `checkAttendance` stream function is also running in-side a loop.

I've to listen to each `attendance` sub-collection constantly. I can't return as `future` since I've to update on live.

I can't use StreamBuilder in this case because, I'm using MVVM architecture [Stacked](https://pub.dev/packages/stacked).

I couldn't able to figure it out. Any would be appreciated.

**UPDATED**

This is how I'm return the markers

```
  final FirestoreService _firestoreService = locator<FirestoreService>();

  Map<MarkerId, Marker> _markers = <MarkerId, Marker>{};
  Map<MarkerId, Marker> get markers => _markers;

  void getMembers(Batch batch) {
    setBusy(true);

    _firestoreService.getMembers(batch.id).listen((event) { //returns the list of members assigned to a batch
      List<Profile> members = event;

      if (members != null && members.length > 0) {
        members.forEach((member) { //loop through list of members
          if (member.attendingDays.contains(toDay) && !member.onVacation) { //validation
            createAttendance(member.id, batch.id);

         //this is code part where I'm checking attendance
            _firestoreService
                .checkAttendance(member: member.id, batch: batch.id)
                .listen((attendanceEvent) { //returns list of attendance records of members
              List<Attendance> attendances = attendanceEvent;

              if (attendances != null && attendances.length > 0) {
                attendances.forEach((attendance) {
                  final MarkerId markerId = MarkerId(member.id);
                  final Marker marker = Marker(
                    markerId: markerId,
                    position: LatLng(
                      member.pickupLatLng.latitude,
                      member.pickupLatLng.longitude,
                    ),
                    icon: (attendance.isComing)
                        ? BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(
                            BitmapDescriptor.hueGreen)
                        : BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
                    flat: true,
                    zIndex: 2,
                    anchor: Offset(0.5, 0.5),
                    onTap: () {},
                  );

                  _markers[markerId] = marker;
                  notifyListeners();
                });
              }
            });
          }
        });
      }

      setBusy(false);
    });
  }
```

Comment: *"How to return multiple streams of data via StreamController?
"* - so you want `StreamController<List<Attendance>>`, not `StreamController<Attendance>`? i mean every element in your stream should be a list of `Attendance` objects and not simple `Attendance`?

Comment: @pskink Even if I return as a `List<Attendance>` it just returns the last profile `document` data only.

Comment: so append the current `data` to some list and call `StreamController.add()` with that list, but actually you can do that with simple `Stream.map` method - no `Stream.forEach`, no `StreamController`s etc

Comment: @pskink Your idea works partially. If I print the value in the terminal, it prints correctly. but    If i update the marker, all the other marker's colours are changing too. And in the terminal , the value prints couple of times. Do you have any idea?

Comment: i dont see any markers in your code so... basically the idea is as: `void main() {
  var list = [];
  Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (i) => i)
    .take(10)
    .map((i) => list..add(i))
    .listen(print);
}` - here you have a stream that generates numbers 0..9 in 1 second delay and `map()` method appends that numbers so the output stream has a growing list of numbers

Comment: @pskink Thanks for you explanation. I update the question. I included how i'm generating markers code. Could you please point out what am I missed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214557/discussion-between-thanooshan-and-pskink).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found a way to change the colour of the marker for my case.

As @pskink suggested I returned the Attendance data as a list.

Then I created following function.

```
  void checkAttendance(String member, String batch) {
    _firestoreService
        .checkAttendance(member: member, batch: batch)
        .listen((attendanceEvent) {
      List<Attendance> attendances = attendanceEvent;

      if (attendances != null && attendances.length > 0) {
        attendances.forEach((attendance) {
          final MarkerId markerId = MarkerId(attendance.profileId);
          final Marker matchedMarker = _markers[markerId];

          if (!attendance.isComing) { //validation
            final Marker newMarker = matchedMarker.copyWith(
                iconParam: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker);
            _markers[markerId] = newMarker;
          } else {
            final Marker newMarker = matchedMarker.copyWith(
                iconParam: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(
                  BitmapDescriptor.hueGreen));
            _markers[markerId] = newMarker;            
          }
          notifyListeners();
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

I already fetching the markers to google map. So, with attendance data I'm returning the `profile id` too. Each `marker_id` equals to `profile id`.

Therefore, what I did was I return the matched `marker_id` and `profile id` and then made a of the matched marker using `.copyWith()` function and the changed the icon colour according to the validation.

At last I found the solution by myself. I hoped this solution might help someone.